# value in input is undefined

Tags: javascript, html

I'm making AP calculator but the answer value is undefined in the input field of answer having id "An"
please help;
here's my code:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>JavaScript Example</title>
</head>

<body>
    <!-- first term -->
    <input type="text" value="1" name="" id="a1" onkeyup="ap()">
    <!-- number of term -->
    <input type="text" value="2" name="" id="n" onkeyup="ap()">
    <!-- difference -->
    <input type="text" name="" value="3" id="d" onkeyup="ap()">
    <input type="text" name="" id="An">

    <script>
        ap()

        function ap() {
            let a1 = document.getElementById("a1").value;

            let n = document.getElementById("n").value;
            let d = document.getElementById("d").value;
            var An = Number(a1) + ((Number(n) - 1) * Number(d));
            console.log(An)
            document.getElementById("An").value = An.value
        }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

please help in solving the issue.

Comment: In your `ap` function, `An` is a *number*, not a DOM `input` element. You don't need `.value` on the right-hand side, just `document.getElementById("An").value = An`.

Comment: Side note: In general, we only use initially-capitalized identifiers for constructor functions, so `An` should probably be `an` (or some other descriptive name). Also, in new code, don't use `var`, use `let` or `const` as you have with `a1`, `n`, and `d`.

Answer (score 0):

Change the An.value to jut An, since An is just a variable

```
document.getElementById("An").value = An;
```

Answer (score 0):

You must assign the variable 'An' direct in the value.

```
document.getElementById("An").value = An
```